# Slot machine infinite loop Trouble in JAVA

Tags: java

I am writing a basic slot machine code and seem to have it stuck in an infinite loop when the program is ran. If any one could shed some light on where about this error is, or something that you would recommend. All the help is appreciated.

```
public class Java_Lab_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int endgame;  
        int slot1;
        int slot2;
        int slot3;

        Random rand =  new Random();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

        System.out.println("Want to test your luck?");
        System.out.println("To Spin, type any positive number");
        System.out.println("To End Game, type -1 and press enter ");

        endgame = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (endgame != -1) {
            slot1 = rand.nextInt(10);
            slot2 = rand.nextInt(10);
            slot3 = rand.nextInt(10);

            System.out.println(slot1 + slot2 + slot3);
            System.out.println(endgame);

            if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3) { // Then they have JACKPOT
                System.out.println("You've Won!");
            } else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) { // They MATCHED 2
               System.out.println("We have twins... You've matched a pair!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sucks to Suck, don't quit your day job!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move 3 lines of sysout & endgame read from scanner inside the while loop.

Comment: are you saying move the sysout staments I made in my if else statements?

Comment: I posted the code in the answer. You were missing on reading endGame prompt from user inside the loop, so user could never exit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to program the possibility for an exit condition if you want to break out of that loop. For example...

```
while (endgame != -1) {
    System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (-1 to quit): ");
    endgame = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

In this way, you prompt the user to play again after every roll.

Comment: great! thanks for the help! I'll give it a try and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

You should put `endgame = keyboard.nextInt();` inside the while. And assign it with some value(for safetyness)

**EDIT : Add the counter feature**

```
    int endgame = 1;  
    int count1 = 0;
    while (endgame != -1) {
        endgame = keyboard.nextInt();
        slot1 = rand.nextInt(10);
        slot2 = rand.nextInt(10);
        slot3 = rand.nextInt(10);

        System.out.println(slot1 + slot2 + slot3);
        count1++;
        System.out.println(count1); //replace here

        if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3) { // Then they have JACKPOT
            System.out.println("You've Won!");
        } else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) { // They MATCHED 2
           System.out.println("We have twins... You've matched a pair!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sucks to Suck, don't quit your day job!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Marfin, I'll give it a try and comment how it goes after i make the changes.

Comment: Now when i try to run the code as is, I input a positive number and it just restarts and doesn't display any numbers for what the user got from the slot machine

Comment: Yes, because your code tell you to input -1 to exit the loop sir.

Comment: i see, i miss- read your comment. Now the only issue i'm having is it is counting the users input to start the game, as a number that the slot game them. For example is I type 3 to start the game it would give me a 3 "the number that I Typed" then two other random variables. Any advice on how i can get it to display a third random number and not count the users input as one of the 3?

Comment: Int count1 = 0; //declare this outside the loop

count1++; //increment of the counter


System.out.println(count1); //replace this with System.out.println(endgame);

I edited the answer to simplify what I mean. Sorry tho xD. It kinda complicated to explain you in comment section.

Comment: All good man I appreciate the help, i'm new to this in an intro class and when it comes to certain errors i just don't have the knowledge to fixing them all yet.

Comment: since ive made your changes im getting the error as follows... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 endgame cannot be resolved to a variable
 endgame cannot be resolved to a variable

 at Java_Lab_3.main(Java_Lab_3.java:15)

Comment: I have no idea why did you get that error because in my compiler it works fine. Here is the result: https://ibb.co/ipNi3d
Here is the code: https://id.imgbb.com/
I didn't see any changes in your post so it is hard for me to check your error.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code, moved user prompt inside the while loop:

```
public class Java_Lab_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int endgame = 0;  
        int slot1;
        int slot2;
        int slot3;

        Random rand =  new Random();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

        while (endgame != -1) {
            System.out.println("Want to test your luck?");
            System.out.println("To Spin, type any positive number");
            System.out.println("To End Game, type -1 and press enter ");

           endgame = keyboard.nextInt();

            slot1 = rand.nextInt(10);
            slot2 = rand.nextInt(10);
            slot3 = rand.nextInt(10);

            System.out.println(slot1 + slot2 + slot3);
            System.out.println(endgame);

            if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3) { // Then they have JACKPOT
                System.out.println("You've Won!");
            } else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) { // They MATCHED 2
               System.out.println("We have twins... You've matched a pair!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sucks to Suck, don't quit your day job!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```